# Get_Posts, only if in both categories

Tags: get-posts

get_posts('numberposts=5&category=93+85')get_posts('numberposts=5&category=9385')

Is there a way to have get_posts grab only posts that are in BOTH categories, as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)'s `category__and`:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category__and' => array( 93, 85 )
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $my_query->have_posts() ):
    $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Where would that go in a situation like this?

<?php global $post; $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category=1'); foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

Comment: it would replace `get_posts`, see edit above.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I mislead. I'm trying to only get posts that are in both categories at the same time. Category__and doesn't do that, no?

Comment: it does, category__in fetches posts that are in one category OR another, category__and fetches posts that have both categories.

Comment: Ah, alright. So now, and I apologize as I'm not too keen on PHP what would I replace this with:

`<?php global $post; $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category=30'); foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

              <?php if ( in_category('1') ) { ?>
 
                <?php include('sidebar-reviews_review.php'); ?>

              <?php } ?>`

To make it pull posts from categories 30 and 1.

Comment: it's a complete replacement of all of the get_posts code, you would change `93, 85` in the example with your category IDs `30, 1`.

Comment: Ah, I see how this works. However, the code I currently have allows for better customization. In that sidebar-review_reviews.php file I mentioned in my earlier post, I'm able to customize the post title, image, excerpt, etc. How do I set up this new code so I'm able to do the same? I'm basically looking for a format like the one I posted.

Comment: without seeing the contents of that file, I can't say for certain, but you can probably just add `include('sidebar-reviews_review.php');` within the `while` loop in place of `the_title();`. all the template tags will work exactly the same in this version as in your original.